# Not able to send bulk of mails at a time using Gmail from AWS server

Tags: spring, email, amazon-ec2, activemq-classic, jakarta-mail

I am using javaMailSender to send mails.

Java mail Producer :

```
    // Publishing the message to the JMS queue.
    queueClinicalMessageServiceTemplate.send(new MessageCreator() {
        public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
            MapMessage mapMessage = session.createMapMessage();
            mapMessage.setStringProperty(ActivemqConstants.KEY_EMAIL_ADDRESS, email);
            mapMessage.setStringProperty(ActivemqConstants.KEY_PASSWORD, password);
            mapMessage.setStringProperty(ActivemqConstants.KEY_REG_MSG_TYPE,
                    ActivemqConstants.VALUE_SEND_CLI_REG_EMAIL);
            return mapMessage;
        }
    });
```

Java mail Consumer :

```
    try {
        logger.debug("JMSMessageID = {}; MSDeliveryMode = {}; JMSRedelivered = {}; JMSQueue = {}.",
                msg.getJMSMessageID(), msg.getJMSDeliveryMode(), msg.getJMSRedelivered(),
                msg.getStringProperty(ActivemqConstants.KEY_REG_MSG_TYPE));
        if (msg instanceof MapMessage) {
            MapMessage mapMsg = (MapMessage) msg;
            String email = mapMsg.getStringProperty(ActivemqConstants.KEY_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
            String password = mapMsg.getStringProperty(ActivemqConstants.KEY_PASSWORD);

            Map<String, String> model = new HashMap<String, String>();
            model.put("password", password);
            emailSender.sendMail(messageSource.getMessage("mail.username", null, null, null), email,
                    "Subject", model,
                    "com/utils/RegistrationEmail.ftl");

        }
    } catch (JMSException ex) {
        logger.error("JMSException:", ex);
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }


public void sendMail(final String from, final String to, final String subject, final Object model,
            final String template) throws MailException {

        MimeMessagePreparator mimeMessagePreparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {

            public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
                MimeMessageHelper mimeMessageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);
                mimeMessageHelper.setFrom(from);
                mimeMessageHelper.setTo(to);
                mimeMessageHelper.setSubject(subject);
                String text = FreeMarkerTemplateUtils
                        .processTemplateIntoString(freemarkerConfiguration.getTemplate(template, "UTF-8"), model);
                // boolean true is for html
                mimeMessageHelper.setText(text, true);
            }
        };

        try {
            logger.info("Attempting to send email via Gmail now");
            javaMailSender.send(mimeMessagePreparator);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.debug("MailException occured while sending the mail for ftl model:::{}::: MailException object::{}",
                    model, e);
            try {
                logger.info("Attempting to send email via Gmail now");
                alternateJavaMailSender.send(mimeMessagePreparator);
            } catch (MailException ae) {
                logger.error(
                        "MailException occured while sending the mail for ftl model:::{}::: MailException object::{}",
                        model, ae);
                throw ae;
            }

        }
    }
```

Mail config

```
mail.username=XXX@gmail.com
mail.password=YYY
mail.host=smtp.gmail.com

mail.smtp.port=25
mail.smtp.auth=true
```

When I run the same code on local system I am able to send all mail successfully(20 to 30 at a time). But on production (AWS) server only 3 to 4 mails are receiving from the bunch of 20 to 30 mails. And getting following exceptions on Production server:

```
10:51:15.667 [userRegEmailDMLC-1] DEBUG [net.abc.xyz.consumer.utils.EmailSender]-MailException occured while sending the mail for ftl model:::{password=AppleGoldDiamond}::: MailExce
ption object::{}
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 25; tim
eout -1;
  nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect. Failed messages: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:432)
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:345)
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:362)
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:350)
        at net.abc.xyz.consumer.utils.EmailSender.sendMail(EmailSender.java:97)
        at net.abc.xyz.consumer.mdp.user.userRegEmailServiceListener.onMessage(userRegEmailServiceListener.java:49)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy72.onMessage(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:746)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:684)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:651)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:317)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:255)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1166)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1158)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1055)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 25; timeout -1
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2053)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:697)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:364)
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.connectTransport(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:501)
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:421)
        ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:312)
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:236)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2019)
        ... 31 common frames omitted
```

What could be the problem because of that I am getting error on Production but not on Local.

Answer (score 0):

By default, EC2 has severe limitation in sending mail, due to security reason. You have to send request to support (log in to your account as root then follow the [link](http://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/ec2-email-limit-request/)), and it is your responsibility to keep the mail stream legitimate.

Nevertheless, **it's recommended to [use SES instead](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/)**.

Answer (score 0):

you probably will find helpful to use MailChimp